# Why does FireFox freeze my inputs in this login form?

Tags: css, firefox, textinput

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qEpVG/).

That's part of my login-page with the entire site stylesheet. This login form works brilliantly in Chrome, but in FireFox it, for some reason, freezes the username input after I've started writing the password, and when you remove focus from the password box, that's frozen too.

Does this happen with you? If yes, any idea why?

---

After Boris' answer my `user-select` [stylus](https://github.com/learnboost/stylus) function now works perfectly and looks like this:

```
user-select()
    user-select arguments
    -webkit-user-select arguments
    -o-user-select arguments

    if arguments == 'none'
        -moz-user-select -moz-none
    else
        -moz-user-select arguments
```

Which on usage renders to this:

`user-select none`:

```
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: -moz-none;
```

`user-select text`:

```
user-select: text;
-webkit-user-select: text;
-o-user-select: text;
-moz-user-select: text;
```

Comment: Doesn't freeze up for me in FF 13.0.1 but I did notice that your use of `user-select:none` is making it impossible for me to select the text with the mouse, which is not exactly user-friendly.

Comment: @TheZ It doesn't make it easy to select the text with the keyboard either - Home and End don't work, so you have to use Left and Right instead.

Comment: I think TheZ has found the problem. Just to answer to Neil, instead of home and end, you could use Ctrl + Right/Left to select text faster. :)

Comment: @TheZ: I very much like `user-select: none` on UI areas that shouldn't be selected anyway. I have set `-moz-user-select: text` on all inputs, so it shouldn't be a problem. Any idea why this doesn't work on FireFox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-moz-user-select: none` means nothing inside it is selectable, period.  It doesn't matter what the styles of the things inside it are.

If you want to be able to override by styling descendants, you want `-moz-user-select: -moz-none`.

Comment: Is FireFox the only browser that does this? It doesn't make sense to me that descendants can't override that property, which is what CSS is all about.

Comment: This is a non-standard property, with no real spec for how it should behave (especially as of when it was implemented in Gecko many years ago).  The behavior that was implemented was the one consumers of the property were asking for at the time...